# How to set background property for all controls, panels, text blocks and so on?

Tags: c#, wpf

I can't do it through style, because all these types have its own Background property. If only the FrameworkElement which is a base type for all of these aforementioned types had a common Background property...

For now I do it through creating Brush as resource and assigning it as Background at each control I want to has such a background. It is one extra line of markup for every control across my UserControl, or Panel, or whatever.

Another way is creating a base style with specified Background (taken as a resource or just hardcoded in each such a style) for each type of controls I use. Also not a convenient way.

Comment: do you mean you want to unify the background of all controls? sounds like theming or skinning https://michaelscodingspot.com/wpf-complete-guide-themes-skins/

Comment: Not fully unifying (I mean not in such a global way like theming or skinning), but assigning across some user control or panel. For me it is just straight and logical that you would assign Backgroung for all types of controls in the same manner. Why every descendant of FrameworkElement (Control, TextBlock, and so on) has its own Background property which you can't assign in unified way at single base style?